# Php, how to get rid of $this ? (not as destroying the current object)

Tags: php

I want to pass informations to a template:

```
public function do(array $p)
{
    extract($p);
    unset($p);
    ob_start();
    require('view.php');
    return ob_get_clean();
}

$object->do([
    'a' => 1
]);
```

view.php

```
<?php
var_dump(get_declared_vars());
```

this way the dump will output `a => 1` and the `$this` object, but I dont want to see `$this`. How to nullify it?

Comment: Is that really an issue that needs to be solved? I'd argue that `$this` in a template can be useful to expose general helper functions.

Comment: Then just filter it out!

Comment: FYI you can't use `do` as a method name, it's a reserved keyword. http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.do.while.php

Comment: @TimBrownlaw and how? :) I cant say to extract that "hey, ignore this name please"

Comment: @BadHorsie: ok, lets not search the bumpmap on the mirror, it was just a sketch

Comment: He is probably doing a `foreach` after this action and doesn't want to include `$this` in that loop.

Comment: @John Smith - Well actually you can. Where does get_declared_vars come from? It doesn't appear to be an inbuilt php function, but I could obviously be extremely wrong!

Answer (score 1):

I tried this...

```
<?php
class forJohn {

    public function test (array $p) {
        extract($p);
        unset( $p );
        ob_start();
        require( 'view.php' );
        return ob_get_clean();
    }
}

$object = new forJohn;
echo $object->test( ['a' => 1] );
```

View.php

```
<?php
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

Interestingly, this results in

```
array (size=1)
  'a' => int 1
```

Now I have had to use get_defined_vars() as I don't have access to your get_declared_vars(). Might be that is the answer!

Answer (score 0):

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

> The pseudo-variable `$this` is available when a method is called from
>   within an object context. `$this` is a reference to the calling object
>   (usually the object to which the method belongs, but possibly another
>   object, if the method is called statically from the context of a
>   secondary object).

This variable is added automatically and it's very useful when trying to access the classes variables from it's method.

```
<?php
class SimpleClass
{
    // property declaration
    public $var = 'a default value';

    // method declaration
    public function displayVar() {
        echo $this->var;
    }
}
?>
```

Why this is bothering you, I don't know, but you can remove this by using:

```
$declared_vars = get_declared_vars();
unset($declared_vars["this"]);
var_dump($declared_vars);
```

(This is not tested because my php version doesn't have the `get_declared_vars()` function, but if it returns an array, this is the path and may need only a few changes.